Does this identity relating to Brier scores $B=E[S]-E[S^2]$ relate to any standard quantity or parameter in probability?
Consider a binary random variable $Y$, and another random variable $S$ which represents a "score", such that $P(Y=1|S=s)=s$ (call this the "calibration" assumption). I'm thinking of $S$ as coming from a machine learning model trained to predict $Y$. The "Brier score" (which is usually calculated empirically, not analytically like this, but bear with me) is basically the mean squared error of the model, $B=E[(Y-S)^2]$. I believe you can easily show that the calibration assumption implies that $$B=E[S]-E[S^2]$$. This identity is very interesting looking and I'm trying to make sense of it in terms of the distribution of $S$. It's related to the mean and the variance of $S$ but not in any totally standard way that I'm aware of. Is this number interesting or significant?

Not sure there is anything deeper than $E[(Y - S)^2 \mid S] = S(1-S)$, which comes from the fact that $p(1-p)$ is the variance of a Bernoulli(p) random variable.
